# Get value of a ComboBoxTableCell

Tags: combobox, javafx, tableview

I used this code to put a ComboBoxCell into my Table named "ComboTable". The data of the first two colums is given by a database-connection below this code.

```
 ComboTable.setEditable(true);
        col1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<model, String>("rCol1"));
        col2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<model, String>("rCol2"));
        col3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<model, String>("rCol3"));
        col3.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(cbValues));

        // ChangeListener
        ComboTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() { 
        @Override
        public void changed (ObservableValue<?> oValue, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
            tableIndexProperty.set(tableData.indexOf(newValue));
            tableIndex = (tableData.indexOf(newValue));
            System.out.println("Index:\t" + tableIndex);
            System.out.println(col3.getCellData(tableIndex));
        }});
```

So now I want to receive the value after setting the value in the table by using a change listener. I thought this code gives me the value after I choosed a value for the comboboxtablecell:

```
System.out.println(col3.getCellData(tableIndex));
```

Where is my mistake at this part if my program or is it the wrong way to get the value?

By the way, here's the output of my program:

```
*** Loaded Oracle-Driver ***
*** Connected with Database ***
Index of Databaserow:   1
Daten1:  one            Daten2: two
Index of Databaserow:   2
Daten1:  tree           Daten2: four

*** Database data saved to Observable List named 'data' ***
*** Table Items setted ***
```

I clicked onto the table rows right here -> ChangeListener:

```
Index:  1
null
Index:  0
null
Index:  1
null
Index:  0
null
```

Model:

```
package model;

import controller.main_controller.ComboValues;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class model {

     private StringProperty rCol1 = new SimpleStringProperty();
     private StringProperty rCol2 = new SimpleStringProperty();
     private ObjectProperty<ComboValues> rCol3 = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();


     public model(String sCol1, String sCol2, ComboValues sCol3) {
         setCol1(sCol1);
         setCol2(sCol2);
         setComboValues(sCol3);
     }

     public final StringProperty col1Property() {
         return this.rCol1;
     }

     public final String setCol1() {
         return this.col1Property().get();
     }

     public final void setCol1(final String col1) {
         this.col1Property().set(col1);
     }

     public final StringProperty col2Property() {
         return this.rCol2;
     }

     public final String setCol2() {
         return this.col2Property().get();
     }

     public final void setCol2(final String col2) {
         this.col1Property().set(col2);
     }

     public final ObjectProperty<ComboValues> combovaluesProperty() {
         return this.rCol3;
     }

     public final ComboValues getComboValues() {
         return this.combovaluesProperty().get();
     }

     public final void setComboValues(final ComboValues rCol3) {
         this.combovaluesProperty().set(rCol3);
     }

}
```

Comment: Did you set the `cellValueFactory` for `col3`? You should really just get the value from the model; if you have things properly set up the model will automatically update when the user commits an edit with the combo box.

Comment: no, its not included in the model. How can i include it there?

Comment: Just create a property for it in the model in the same way you have properties for the other columns... Hard to answer without knowing what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I think it's clear what i want to do. I want to split the combobox from the model. And after loading the first two colmums i want to set a value in the third col by myself. after that i want to get the value i choosed by clicking on the row

Comment: No, sorry, not clear at all, at least not to me. It doesn't make any sense to have data that is separate from the model; the model by definition represents the data you are displaying. Another way to think of this perhaps: you need to tell the cell what data to display; that's what the cell value factory is for. That data needs to be stored somewhere.

Comment: thats right of coure, but when i create a property in my model, how can i modify the cellvaluefactory? : `col3.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new DefaultStringConverter(), cbValues));` and after that i want to get the value which i choosed in the comboboxcell, you know? I have to work with the value to generate the UPDATE-Command for the database...

Comment: Just use the `cellValueFactory` the same way as you do for the other columns. The `cellFactory` you have that generates the `ComboBox` does not need to change. I'm not sure I understand what the question is. You get the value selected from the model; the cell will automatically update that when the user selects something (assuming everything is set up correctly). Perhaps it would help if you posted the code from your model.

Comment: I dont know what you are not understanding. At col 3 i Write something with a comboboxcell. How can I combine this with the Link to the model? I think the property is not the Problem

Comment: Just use the `cellFactory` you have posted, that generates the `ComboBoxTableCell`, and *also* set a `cellValueFactory` that maps to the property. You need both of them for this column. If you edit to include your model class I could post some code, but I can't without it.

Comment: i posted the model class..

Comment: You are missing the "property accessor" methods. `public StringProperty rCol3Property() { ... }` etc. As explained in the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html), the `PropertyValueFactory` needs these, otherwise it creates a `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper`, which it cannot update (since it's read only).

Comment: can you give me an example code for the model?

Comment: There is already a complete example in my answer. The Person class is the model for the table in that example.

Comment: i changed model like in your example. Here's a screenshot of the failure. [link](http://abload.de/img/cellfactorywrktb.png)

Comment: So fix the types. If `rCol3` is a `String`, you can hardly expect the `ComboBox` to provide something of type `ComboValues`. Just follow the example I provided.

Comment: it's not a string.[pic](http://abload.de/img/notastringeos9t.png) this ist a pic from the model.

Comment: That contradicts the code you posted for your model, in which you clearly define `rCol3` as a `String` property. I am not going to waste any more time on this; I have already written a complete example specifically for you, which clearly answers your question. If you are unable to use that, then I don't think there is anything more I can do for you.

Comment: i have written that i've changed to model code like this in your example. I did not update the code from my question. I'm sorry, that i'm not a java champion. I did the things which I understood. I'll update my code from the question now.

Comment: code works now. I had to change the declaration of my table columns from `private TableColumn<model, String> col3;` to `private TableColumn<model, ComboValues> col3;` i have to test it tomorrow when i have the database connection working

Comment: now the right value is returned, but the model isn't able to set col1 and col2 in the right way. But your example works perfect^^ don't know my mistake, no code errors, database return values^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you haven't set a `cellValueFactory` for that column, so there is no data associated with it. Thus when you call `getCellData(...)`, which looks for the value of the cell, it (of course) returns `null`. Just set a `cellValueFactory` on your column that maps into the model in the same way you do for the columns using the default `cellFactory`.

Here is an example, using the standard contact table from the Oracle tutorials:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.ComboBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewWithComboColumn extends Application {

    public enum Category { Friends, Family, Work, Other }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First name");
        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last name");
        TableColumn<Person, String> emailCol = new TableColumn<>("Email");
        TableColumn<Person, Category> categoryCol = new TableColumn<>("Category");


        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
        // or firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName")); etc

        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty());
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().emailProperty());

        categoryCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().categoryProperty());
        categoryCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(Category.values()));

        ObservableList<Person> tableData = createData();
        table.setItems(tableData);

        table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelectedPerson, newSelectedPerson) -> {
            int tableIndex = tableData.indexOf(newSelectedPerson) ;
            System.out.println("Index:\t" + tableIndex);
            System.out.println(categoryCol.getCellData(tableIndex));
            // better: just get the data from the model:
            System.out.println(newSelectedPerson.getCategory());
        });

        table.getColumns().addAll(Arrays.asList(
             firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol, categoryCol   
        ));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(table), 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private ObservableList<Person> createData() {
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com", Category.Family),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com", Category.Friends),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com", Category.Work),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com", Category.Work),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com", Category.Other)
        );
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty() ;
        private final ObjectProperty<Category> category = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email, Category category) {
            setFirstName(firstName);
            setLastName(lastName);
            setEmail(email);
            setCategory(category);
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public final String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }

        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public final String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setLastName(final String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }

        public final StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return this.email;
        }

        public final String getEmail() {
            return this.emailProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setEmail(final String email) {
            this.emailProperty().set(email);
        }

        public final ObjectProperty<Category> categoryProperty() {
            return this.category;
        }

        public final Category getCategory() {
            return this.categoryProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setCategory(final Category category) {
            this.categoryProperty().set(category);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: i created a property in my table and changed the main code at col3.setCellValue.... i edited in my first post. But i did'nt unterstand how it works with the object in the table. And i don't understand how there is the "newSelectedPerson" in the ChangeListener..

Comment: I edited my ChangeListener to yours, i want to get the value with the "better" way `ComboTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            int tableIndex = tableData.indexOf(newValue) ;
            System.out.println("Index:\t" + tableIndex);
//            System.out.println(col3.getCellData(tableIndex));
            // better: just get the data from the model:
            System.out.println("Value:\t" + newValue.getRCol3());
        });` But the output says: `Value: null
Index: 0`